# Randomly pair 10 elements without duplicates

Tags: php, for-loop, random

At this point my script is half working, i get no duplicated results, but i don't always get 10 results. What i need is a way to start the loop again until i hit 10 results without any duplicates. Any help would be much appreciated! 
Here's the script:

```
$randomlist = array
    (
    array('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6', 'A7', 'A8' , 'A9' , 'A10'),
    array('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6', 'A7', 'A8' , 'A9' , 'A10'),
    array('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6', 'A7', 'A8' , 'A9' , 'A10'),
    );

shuffle($randomlist[1]);
shuffle($randomlist[2]);
$c = count($randomlist);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{

if ($randomlist[0][$i] != $randomlist[1][$i])
    {
    $randomlist[0][$i] = $randomlist[0][$i]."/";
    $pairNumber = $randomlist[0][$i] . $randomlist[1][$i];
        echo $pairNumber.'<br>';
    }  
}
```

This is an output example of what i get (only 8 results)

```
A1/A2
A2/A8
A4/A6
A5/A9
A6/A4
A8/A1
A9/A10
A10/A5
```

Comment: You could use `while`?

Comment: Can u please elaborate a little more. I am not sure how that would make a difference !

Comment: `while` loops just as long until you have 10 pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might simplifies it:

```
$elements = array('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6', 'A7', 'A8' , 'A9' , 'A10');

$found = array();
while (count($found) < 10) {
    $temp = $elements[array_rand($elements)] . '/' . $elements[array_rand($elements)];
    if (!in_array($temp, $found)) {
        $found[] = $temp;
    }
}

print_r($found);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a stray comma at the end of the third line of arrays:

```
array('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6', 'A7', 'A8' , 'A9' , 'A10'),
                                                        -------^
```

Here's a method - we just need a total output variable so that the loop continues until it has output ten total pairs. $i is continually reset until the total condition is met:

```
$total = 0; $i = 0;
while($total < 10){ 
    if ($i == 9) {
        $i=0;
    }
    if ($randomlist[0][$i] != $randomlist[1][$i]){
        echo $randomlist[0][$i] ."/". $randomlist[1][$i] ."<br>";
        $total++;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not a stray. I always add commas in the end to make it easier to add new items later on (easier to diff).

Answer (score 1):

This version makes sure there are not any two matching pairs, and that the same two values are not used twice. Here's a sandbox version of it working:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc6c749a6ec9a68bd9bf0ea98d6f3bc347141607

```
$randomlist = array
    (
    array('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6', 'A7', 'A8' , 'A9' , 'A10'),
    array('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6', 'A7', 'A8' , 'A9' , 'A10')
    );

$newlist = array();

shuffle($randomlist[0]);
shuffle($randomlist[1]);

while ( count($newlist) < 10 ) 
{
  //check if both values are not equal
  //and that they are not in $newlist already
  if ( end($randomlist[0]) !== end($randomlist[1]) && !in_array(end($randomlist[0]).'/'.end($randomlist[1]), $newlist) )
  {

     //remove last values from array and add them to new array
     $l0 = array_pop($randomlist[0]);
     $l1 = array_pop($randomlist[1]);

     array_push($newlist, $l0.'/'.$l1);
  } 
  //otherwise, reshuffle.
  else 
  {
     shuffle($randomlist[0]);
     shuffle($randomlist[1]);
  }
}

var_dump($newlist);
```